# asyncio aiohttp progress bar with tqdm

Tags: progress-bar, python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp, tqdm

I'm attempting to integrate a `tqdm` progress bar to monitor POST requests generated with `aiohttp` in Python 3.5. I have a working progress bar but can't seem to gather results using `as_completed()`. Pointers gratefully received.

Examples I've found suggest using the following pattern, which is incompatible with Python 3.5 `async def` definitions:

```
for f in tqdm.tqdm(asyncio.as_completed(tasks), total=len(coros)):
    yield from f
```

Working (albeit redacted) async code without the progress bar:

```
def async_classify(records):

    async def fetch(session, name, sequence):
        url = 'https://app.example.com/api/v0/search'
        payload = {'sequence': str(sequence)}
        async with session.post(url, data=payload) as response:
            return name, await response.json()

    async def loop():
        auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth(api_key)
        conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)
        with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=auth, connector=conn) as session:
            tasks = [fetch(session, record.id, record.seq) for record in records]
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)    
        return OrderedDict(responses)
```

This is my unsuccessful attempt at modifying `loop()`:

```
async def loop():
    auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth(api_key)
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(auth=auth, connector=conn) as session:
        tasks = [fetch(session, record.id, record.seq) for record in records]
        for f in tqdm.tqdm(asyncio.as_completed(tasks), total=len(tasks)):
            await f
        responses = await asyncio.gather(f)
        print(responses)
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`await f` returns a *single* response. Why would you pass an already completed `Future` to `asyncio.gather(f)` is unclear.

Try:

```
responses = []
for f in tqdm.tqdm(asyncio.as_completed(tasks), total=len(tasks)):
    responses.append(await f)
```

---

Python 3.6 implements [PEP 530 -- Asynchronous Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/):

```
responses = [await f
             for f in tqdm.tqdm(asyncio.as_completed(tasks), total=len(tasks))]
```

It works inside `async def` functions now.