# tqdm for asyncio in jupyter notebook

Tags: tqdm

I'm using tqdm for an async action in my Jupyter notebook -- should I use `tqdm.notebook` (which I think gets me the right widget) or `tqdm.asyncio` (which probably gets me the right behavior -- the items/sec calc seems off in my use).

Comment: any advice on which of these you went with? i have a tqdm notebook but am considering trying to write my for loop with asyncio

Comment: I went with tqdm.notebook

Answer (score 1):

You can use an asyncio compatible version of tqdm in a jupyter notebook, by using the solution from [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61041328/19333245):

and replacing the tqdm you use, with the notebook version:

```py
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

async def factorial(name, number):
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number + 1):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
        f *= i
    return f"Task {name}: factorial {number} = {f}"

requests = [factorial("A", 2), factorial("B", 3), factorial("C", 4)]
responses = [await f for f in tqdm(asyncio.as_completed(requests), total=len(requests))]
```