# Asyncio and TQDM Python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, tqdm

I am trying to make a progress bar using tqdm for an asyncio function. I've tried following the guidance at:

[tqdm for asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041214/making-a-tqdm-progress-bar-for-asyncio)
and
[asyncio with tqdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901292/asyncio-aiohttp-progress-bar-with-tqdm)
and
[tqdm and coroutines](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/examples/async_coroutines.py)

Here's my code, which is running in a jupyter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import asyncio
# import tqdm
from tqdm.asyncio import tqdm


async def get_prices(index, row):
    try:
        prices = pdr.get_data_yahoo(row['Symbol'], row['Start'], row['End'])
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error',e,row['Symbol'],row['Date'])
        return
    prices['Symbol'] = row['Symbol']
    prices['Key'] = index
    return prices

async def get_stock_data(df):
    # data = await asyncio.gather(*[get_prices(index, row) for index, row in df.iterrows()])
    # data = [await f for f in tqdm(asyncio.as_completed([get_prices(index, row) for index, row in df.iterrows()]), total=len(df)]
    flist = [get_prices(index, row) for index, row in df.iterrows()]
    data = [await f for f in tqdm.as_completed(flist, total=len(df))]
    return data


stocks = ['IBM', 'AAPL', 'C', 'ACTG', 'ACVA', 'ACWI', 'ACWX', 'ACXP', 'ADAG', 'ADAL', 'IBET', 'IBEX', 'IBKR', 'IBOC', 'IBRX', 'IBTB', 'IBTD', 'IBTE', 'IBTF', 'IBTG', 'IBTH', 'IBTI', 'IBTJ', 'IBTK', 'IBTL', 'IBTM', 'IBTX', 'ICAD', 'ICCC', 'ICCH', 'ICCM', 'ICFI', 'ICHR', 'ICLK', 'ICLN', 'ICLR', 'ICMB', 'ICPT', 'ICUI', 'ICVX', 'IDAI', 'IDBA', 'IDCC', 'IDEX', 'IDLB', 'IDN', 'IDRA', 'IDXX', 'IDYA', 'IEA', 'IEAWW', 'IEF', 'IEI', 'IEP', 'IESC', 'IEUS', 'IFBD', 'IFGL', 'IFRX', 'IFV', 'IGAC', 'IGACU', 'IGACW', 'IGF', 'IGIB', 'IGIC', 'IGICW', 'IGMS', 'IGNY', 'IGNYU', 'IGNYW', 'IGOV', 'IGSB', 'IGTA', 'IGTAR', 'IGTAU', 'IGTAW', 'IHRT', 'IHYF', 'III', 'IIII', 'IIIIU', 'IIIIW', 'IIIV', 'IINN', 'IINNW', 'IIVI', 'IIVIP', 'IJT', 'IKNA', 'IKT', 'ILAG', 'ILMN', 'ILPT', 'IMAB', 'IMAC', 'IMACW', 'IMAQ', 'IMAQR', 'IMAQU', 'IMAQW', 'IMBI', 'IMBIL', 'IMCC', 'IMCR', 'IMCV', 'IMGN', 'IMGO', 'IMKTA', 'IMMP', 'IMMR', 'IMMX', 'IMNM', 'IMOS', 'IMPL', 'IMPP', 'IMPPP', 'IMRA', 'IMRN', 'IMRX', 'IMTE', 'IMTX', 'IMTXW', 'IMUX', 'IMV', 'IMVT', 'IMXI', 'INAB', 'INBK', 'INBKZ', 'INBX', 'INCR', 'INCY', 'INDB', 'INDI', 'INDIW', 'INDP', 'INDT', 'INDY', 'INFI', 'INFN', 'INGN', 'INKA', 'INKAU', 'INKAW', 'INKT', 'INM', 'INMB', 'INMD', 'INNV', 'INO', 'INOD', 'INPX', 'INSE', 'INSG', 'INSM', 'INTA', 'INTC', 'INTE', 'INTEU', 'INTEW', 'INTG', 'INTR', 'INTU', 'INTZ', 'INVA', 'INVE', 'INVO', 'INVZ', 'INVZW', 'INZY', 'IOAC', 'IOACU', 'IOACW', 'IOBT', 'IONM', 'IONR', 'IONS', 'IOSP', 'IOVA', 'IPA', 'IPAR', 'IPAX', 'IPAXU', 'IPAXW', 'IPDN', 'IPGP', 'IPHA', 'IPKW', 'IPSC', 'IPVI', 'IPVIU', 'IPVIW', 'IPW', 'IPWR', 'IPX', 'IQ', 'IQMD', 'IQMDU', 'IQMDW', 'IRAA', 'IRAAU', 'IRAAW', 'IRBT', 'IRDM', 'IREN', 'IRIX', 'IRMD', 'IROQ', 'IRTC', 'IRWD', 'ISAA', 'ISDX', 'ISEE']  
df_stocks = pd.DataFrame(stocks, columns=['Symbol'])
df_stocks['Start'] = '9/1/2022'
df_stocks['End'] = '9/11/2022'

data = pd.concat([d for d in await get_stock_data(df_stocks)])
data.dropna(inplace=True)
data.to_csv('../output/stockprices.csv', sep='\t')
data
```

The code works, but the progress bar does not. I get this output which does not change:

```
0%|          | 0/214 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

I have also tried `from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm`, but that gives the same result.

I am sure I'm doing something boneheaded, but am unable to solve this on my own.

Comment: Would you mind rewriting code as self-contained, minimal reproducible example? It would help people here figure out issue faster! Especially clarifying names like `pdr` and stock data which never been defined in given code.

Comment: Updated. Apologies, should have done that. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Problem is that *Async Function* `get_prices()` doesn't have any [*Awaitable*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables), hence it's *not async* but synchronous. You will definitely want to understand what [`Coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) is before reading the rest of this.

Since that library `pandas-datareader` does not define any asynchronous function - you might be better offloading the `pdr.get_data_xxx` to thread or give up concurrency and use synchronous tqdm.

---

### Explanation

Problem-wise, what you wrote could be simplified as following:

```py
import asyncio
import random
import time
from tqdm.asyncio import tqdm


async def fake_async_task():
    time.sleep(0.5 + random.random())  # <- notice there is no await & awaitable!


async def main():
    tasks = [fake_async_task() for _ in range(10)]
    _ = [await task_ for task_ in tqdm.as_completed(tasks, total=len(tasks))]


# asyncio.run(main()) --> when not in Jupyter
await main() # --> in Jupyter
```

If you run this, you'll notice this also seemingly jumps the progress from 0% to 100% just before it ends, and total execution takes much longer than 0.5 + α seconds.

```
  0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

Reason behind it is quite complicated; Throwing a *fake async function* - aka async func without `await` - is outside of the documented usages, thus requires looking inside the library codes.

To overly simplify the flows - at cost of accuracy & proper terminology:

1. We feed 10 `fake_async_task()` coroutines to `tqdm.asyncio.tqdm.as_completed`.
2. `tqdm.asyncio.tqdm.as_completed` is merely a wrapper for `asyncio.as_completed`, so tqdm pass all given *Awaitable* to it then wait for any results.
3. `asyncio.as_completed` schedule execution of all given *Awaitable*, **and then** schedule *Awaitable* named `_wait_for_one` for getting results.
4. First scheduled `fake_async_task()` starts running, until next `await` keyword it encounters.
5. But we haven't put any `await` keywords, so coroutine ends up running start to end without stopping.
6. Same thing happens for other 9 scheduled `fake_async_task()`, and `_wait_for_one` is still patiently waiting for it's turn.
7. when it's finally `_wait_for_one`'s turn, all tasks are already done, so yielding result happens faster than human eyes can see, so is the progress bar's progress changes.

That's why total execution time was `addictive`, it never really archived any concurrency during execution.

Running functions like `fake_async_task()` is simply neither `tqdm` authors nor `asyncio` had in mind. Others would usually write codes like this instead:

```py
import asyncio
import random
from tqdm.asyncio import tqdm


async def task():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5 + random.random()) # <- await + something that's awaitable
    # adding random val to prevent it finishing altogether,
    # or progress bar will seemingly jump from 0 to 100 again.


async def main():
    tasks = [task() for _ in range(10)]
    _ = [await task_ for task_ in tqdm.as_completed(tasks, total=len(tasks))]


# asyncio.run(main())
await main()
```

Which now then print out progress - more like, slow enough so we can see - just as we wanted. Also, total execution time was 0.5 + α seconds, achieving proper concurrency.

```
 30%|███       | 3/10 [00:00<00:01,  3.98it/s]
```

---

### Alternatives

But if function you want to use happened to not have `async` variant, yet it is gladly [not CPU intensive, but I/O intensive](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock), then you can offload it to another thread to achieve concurrency while using asynchronous APIs.

```py
import asyncio
import random
import time
from tqdm.asyncio import tqdm


def io_intensive_sync_task():
    time.sleep(0.5 + random.random())

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.to_thread(io_intensive_sync_task) for _ in range(10)]
    _ = [await task_ for task_ in tqdm.as_completed(tasks, total=len(tasks))]
    # can skip the total param as tqdm internally use len if not provided


# asyncio.run(main())
await main()
```

Which will run just as the previous example does.

Comment: Incredible helpful and clear, and helps make clear what is going on with concurrency in Python. Thank you!

Comment: Quick note, when running in Jupyter last line should be `await main()`, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55409641/asyncio-run-cannot-be-called-from-a-running-event-loop-when-using-jupyter-no

Comment: @dsagman Updated accordingly, nice catch!